# Error installing Package Control for Sublime Text 3 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, sublime-text

This is the error. It comes up when I paste and enter the installation code (which I get from the Package Control website) and each time I open up Sublime Text.

> Package Control
>
> Your system's locale is set to a value that can not handle non-ASCII
>   characters. Package Control can not properly work unless this is
>   fixed.
>
> On Linux, please reference your distribution's docs for information on
>   properly setting the LANG environmental variable. As a temporary
>   work-around, you can launch Sublime Text from the terminal with:
>
> LANG=en_US.UTF-8 sublime_text

I had the same problem with Ubuntu 13.04 so it's probably not version-dependent.

Comment: So what have you found when searching the Ubuntu docs for setting the `LANG` variable?

Comment: `echo $LANG` gives `en_US.UTF-8` so it looks like my `LANG` variable is already set to what Sublime Text requires.

Answer (score 0):

I found some language settings were missing on my install of 14.04 that make this an easy fix:

1. Install the language settings for system settings

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install language-selector-gnome
   ```
2. Go into Language settings (should be visisble from system settings now) and set your language to English (US) and apply system wide
3. Restart

Answer (score 0):

The environmental variables definied in `.bashrc` and/or `.profile` files are not seen by graphical applications like Sublime Text.
To solve this problem, add a line in `/etc/profile` like this:

`export LANG=en_US.UTF-8`

If you prefer, you ca also use `export LANG=it_IT.UTF-8` or any other language (ES, FR,...).